# Java SDK Manager Crashes with "flashplayerplugin" in the command line output

Tags: java, android, command-line

I read few topics about `sdk manger` and java issues but my problem doesn't correspond to any.
When i'm launching `SDK manager.exe` I get as output :

```
flashplayerplugin
```

As I was thinking that it was a Java issue I've launched `sdk\tools\libs\find_java.exe` (the .bat returns a blank line)

I get as output :

```
flashplayerpluginC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe
```

I really don't understand why this `flashplayerplugin` is coming in the output and crashing the program.

Comment: The `find_java.bat` doesn't do anything beside containing a goto statement, so the correct file to run is `find_java.exe`, it does output a correct path to your JDK Java runtime. What if you open a `cmd` prompt and try and run the java, like this for example: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe" -version`. Also, I'd really make sure to run any antivirus/spyware programs, you should never get the string *flashplayerplugin* in front of your drive-letter unless something is really wrong.

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe" -version` shows the version of Java, I don't have any flashplayerplugin coming in the ouptut.

My antivirus is updated. I'm going to check for spyware.

Comment: @chrkad Antivirus nor Anti Spyware aren't detecting something (kaspersky and spybot). I have uninstalled flashplayer also but the string before the drive still comes up.

Comment: Please take some screenshots when you start SDK Manager and also running "java -version" like you did above; edit your post and add them.

Comment: Is there anything in the environment variables on your PC such as the PATH environment variable that includes the flashplayerplugin. As @chrkad said, having flashplayerplugin output before the driver letter is probably a sign that there something odd is installed which shouldn't be

Comment: In atleast Windows XP/Windows 7, the PROMPT isn't set to a custom value, but instead uses the default `$p$g`, $p is `DriveLetter:\ ` and $g is `>` (greater-than sign), so I can manually replicate his prompt with the command `PROMPT flashplayerplugin$p$g`. So I'd go check in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System` (copy&paste in Explorer Address bar) and then **Advanced system settings** and **Environment variables** and look for the **PROMPT** variable, and remove it. That's how I managed to replicate his output. But it still doesn't solve his issue with starting the SDK Manager :(

Comment: Here is what I get from `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe" -version` : `java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)`. Nothing special. @chrkad : I checked my Environment variables and I didn't see any prompt. PATH is : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin.

Comment: I also have `Path` as system variable : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Python33\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;

Comment: C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ruby-1.9.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\`and QTJAVA : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip`

Comment: Where is your SDK Manager installed? How about opening the `cmd` prompt manually and then starting the SDK Manager from the command line? My command to start it is `"C:\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe"`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same issue. My problem was caused by the tool `airfoil`. It wrotes a registry entry on:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Rogue Amoeba\Airfoil\WhiteList\WhiteListItem_12`

with entry:

`name = *flashplayerplugin`

Solution: just remove the `*` before `flashplayerplugin` and then `SDK Manager.exe` will start properly.

Comment: Thank you very much ! That was it! How did you find out the origin of the problem ?

Comment: Does anyone know HOW that text gets into the output of the command line?  I'm dying to know.

Comment: BTW, Andreas deserves a medal for figuring this out.  This was making my (work) life absolutely miserable.

Comment: I lost a day of development to this issue. Your solution worked perfectly. Thanks!!! :)

Comment: Man, How did you find that !? Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue with Java, it's an issue with Flash. See [this Super User thread](https://superuser.com/questions/567203/cmd-exe-text-injection-whats-going-on). The poster there was able to solve it, but I could not and had to use System Restore to get back to the point before I updated to the latest Flash player. In my case I think the difference may have been Chrome's custom Flash player.

Comment: +1 - Flash is causing the problem. Removing all traces of flash / reinstalling have not helped. Nothing in the registry as far as I can tell. All environment variables seems untouched. Really keen on getting to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply un-installing Airfoil worked for me if this is an option for you.

Answer (score -3):

Update Flash Player and Java...might help

Comment: I did it but it has no effect.

Comment: There is no correlation or requirement of Flash with either Java, Android or the SDK. He is already running the latest *JAVA** JDK.

Comment: Well it was worth a try sometimes the most annoying bugs and problems arise from simple issues like updating for example.