# Git bash always says the branch is ((unknown)) in all directories

Tags: git, fatal-error

Something very strange happened to GIT on my Windows 7 machine recently. Using GIT bash, if I change to *any* directory on any hard drive on my computer, I see:

```
Adam@C-ADAM ~ ((unknown))
```

Where the `~` is variable depending on the current directory.

If I run `git status` I get the following output:

```
flashplayerpluginfatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories):
.git
```

The clue must be in the `flashplayerplugin`, however, I've searched for this folder on my computer and I cannot find anything relating to `.git`.

If I navigate to an actual GIT repository directory on my computer I get:

```
Adam@C-ADAM /d/WWW/yii-projects/irish-health-pro (flashplayerpluginrefs/heads/ma
ster)
```

My other guess is that some directory in my `$PATH` variable might contain a `.git` directory.  However, I've been through these and I cannot find anything obvious:

```
$ echo $PATH
/c/Users/Adam/bin:.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/c/Python27/:/c/Python27/Scri
pts:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Program Files/Comm
on Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows
/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/EXEs:/c/Program Fi
les (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Se
rver/100/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn/:/c/xamp
p/apache/bin:/c/xampp/mysql/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/cwRsync/bin:/c/EXEs:/c/EX
Es/ffmpeg/bin:/c/EXEs/gource:/c/xampp/php:/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSys
tem/:/c/Users/Adam/AppData/Roaming/Python/Scripts:/c/Program Files/Common Files/
Microsoft Shared/Windows Live
```

I've reinstalled GIT, but it makes no difference.

If I run git gui from any folder I get:

[image: git gui fatal error]

Has anyone seen something like this before and knows how to resolve? I cannot use Git at all on this computer any more and I'm desperate to get some work done this weekend!

## Edit

As requested:

```
$ cd; set -x
++ __git_ps1
++ local pcmode=no
++ local detached=no
++ local 'ps1pc_start=\u@\h:\w '
++ local 'ps1pc_end=\$ '
++ local 'printf_format= (%s)'
++ case "$#" in
++ printf_format=' (%s)'
+++ __gitdir
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ '[' -n '' ']'
+++ '[' -n '' ']'
+++ '[' -d .git ']'
+++ git rev-parse --git-dir
++ local g=flashplayerplugin
++ '[' -z flashplayerplugin ']'
++ local r=
++ local b=
++ '[' -f flashplayerplugin/rebase-merge/interactive ']'
++ '[' -d flashplayerplugin/rebase-merge ']'
++ '[' -d flashplayerplugin/rebase-apply ']'
++ '[' -f flashplayerplugin/MERGE_HEAD ']'
++ '[' -f flashplayerplugin/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD ']'
++ '[' -f flashplayerplugin/BISECT_LOG ']'
+++ git symbolic-ref HEAD
++ b=flashplayerplugin
++ detached=yes
++ b=flashplayerplugin
+++ cut -c1-7 flashplayerplugin/HEAD
++ b=...
++ b=unknown
++ b='(unknown)'
++ local w=
++ local i=
++ local s=
++ local u=
++ local c=
++ local p=
+++ git rev-parse --is-inside-git-dir
++ '[' true = flashplayerplugin ']'
+++ git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
++ '[' true = flashplayerplugin ']'
++ local f=
++ '[' no = yes ']'
++ printf -- ' (%s)' '(unknown)'
```

## Edit

Adding more info as requested:

```
Adam@C-ADAM ~ ((unknown))
$ set | grep -F GIT
                            case "${GIT_PS1_DESCRIBE_STYLE-}" in
            b="GIT_DIR!";
            if [ -n "${GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE-}" ]; then
            if [ -n "${GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE-}" ]; then
            if [ -n "${GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES-}" ]; then
            if [ -n "${GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM-}" ]; then
        if [ -n "${GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS-}" ]; then
            GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="$value";
            if [[ -z "${GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM}" ]]; then
for option in ${GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM};
                upstream=${GIT_SVN_ID:-git-svn};
        if [ -n "${GIT_DIR-}" ]; then
            test -d "${GIT_DIR-}" || return 1;
            echo "$GIT_DIR";
Adam@C-ADAM ~ ((unknown))
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[user]
    name = Adam xxxx
    email = adamxxxx@gmail.com
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool "bc3"]
    path = c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe
[merge]
    tool = bc3
[mergetool "bc3"]
    path = c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe
Adam@C-ADAM ~ ((unknown))
$ command -V git
git is hashed (/bin/git)
Adam@C-ADAM ~ ((unknown))
$ git --version
flashplayerplugingit version 1.8.1.msysgit.1
Adam@C-ADAM ~ ((unknown))
```

Comment: @StevenPenny I've edited the post to include the info.

Comment: `$ file /bin/git
sh.exe": file: command not found
$ less /bin/git
/bin/git: No such file or directory
$ ls -la /bin/git
-rwxr-xr-x  109 Adam     Administ  1371136 Apr 21 17:46 /bin/git
$ ldd /bin/git
sh.exe": ldd: command not found`

Comment: `$ hash -r && command -V git
git is /bin/git`
$ git status
flashplayerpluginfatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories):
 .git

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28608/discussion-between-richard-hansen-and-adamski)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- you recently installed Rogue Amoeba Airfoil.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15598704/712605
- Your `GIT_DIR` environment variable is set to `flashplayerplugin`.  Try running `unset GIT_DIR`.
- `git` invokes a shell function instead of the `git` utility.  Try running `unset -f git`.
- `git` is a shell alias that's doing something funny.  Try running `unalias git`.
- `git` is a shell script that's doing something funny.
- There's filesystem corruption.

If none of those work, you'll need to provide more info.  Please update your question with the output of the following commands:

- `set | grep -F GIT`
- `cat ~/.gitconfig`
- `command -V git`
- `git --version`

Comment: @Steven none of your suggestions have worked... I've added more info as requested by Richard.  The output of `git --version` is very strange indeed...

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me in the chat session.  Airfoil caused this nightmare issue... I am contacting them now!

Answer (score 1):

Building off
[Richard’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16125003),
I can replicate this by changing the `__git_dir` variable. For a workaround you can `unset` this variable.

```
Steven@STEVEN-PC ~
$ __git_dir=flashplayerplugin

Steven@STEVEN-PC ~ ((unknown))
$ unset __git_dir

Steven@STEVEN-PC ~
$
```